# Version 7.1 (7B91b) and TFS Authentication

Tags: tfs, xcode7

We are working on Xcode Project connected to our local TFS 2012 Server via TFS Provided GIT Repository.

When we use older version of Xcode, we are successfully able to check-in the files and perform all other GIT operations. We are also able to perform all GIT Operations via command line GIT.

The trouble is when we use latest version of Xcode - Version 7.1 (7B91b). On entering valid credentials, we are getting error saying

Authentication failed because the user name or password was incorrect.

The same credentials / configuration work on older version of Xcode and GIT Command Line Options.

To add more to the surprises, we are able to connect to github.com successfully.

We are able to reproduce issue on other systems too. Please provide us the best way to resolve this error.

Comment: You may try to upgrade to Xcode 7.2 beta 2 to see whether the issue persists

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue? I have the same one. It still worked from terminal but Xcode do nothing...